# Kernel Panic not syncing fatal exception error

Tags: centos, windows, virtualbox, kernel-panic

I'm using Windows 10 and I'm trying to launch CentOS 7 in Virtual Box, but I am getting the following error:

```bsh
Kernel Panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
```

I've tried to solve the error by following several guides by Googling, but to no avail. Could someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the latest ISO: http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/